# python-magic WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-magic, libmagic

Hi I'm trying to use python-magic on windows 8 but when I try to import with the command `import magic` it gives me this error `WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application` I have tried both with 64-bit and 32-bit version of Python 2.7.10 but I always get this error.

Thx

Comment: Same problem! Did you solve it?

Comment: I have the same problem. I've tried this: https://github.com/pidydx/libmagicwin64 and have spent days searching for a solution, but with no result so far. I've also tried what the answers recommended, but neither of them helped. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue installing the library "**python-magic-bin**" using the command `pip install python-magic-bin`

Answer (score 0):

Found it here: https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/issues/24k

> Resolved this by installing the 64-bit version of Cygwin
>   (http://cygwin.com/install.html) and copying the following list of
>   DLLs from \bin to C:\Windows\System32:
>
> - `cygwin1.dll`
> - `cygz.dll`
> - `cygmagic-1.dll` (Don't forget to rename it to `magic1.dll`)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for me was installing Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools ([from here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126)).
But it's a quite heavy dependency for magic to work under python 2.7.